# Remove rows from a file with awk

Tags: awk

I'd like to remove rows from a tab deliminated text file if a certain string is present in a specified column.

Example, 
If column 20  equals 5T, remove all rows from file and print remainder.

I'd also like to be able to do this for multiple values in column 20

Remove rows if column 20 equals 5T, 6T, and 7T.

Comment: By "remove rows", do you mean "output the rows until then and then stop"?

Comment: Can provide examples of output and input files?

Answer (score 1):

***awk*** solution, according to your description:

```
awk -F'\t' '$20!~/^[567]T$/' file
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately this doesn't work.

Comment: @Meghan, *doesn't work* - is not a description of the problem. There must be some errors or other issues that you need to describe

Comment: Sorry my response was sent to quickly.  I was able to make it work with the following: awk -F'\t' '$20!="5T"&& $20!="4T"&& $20!="7T"' input.txt> output.txt

Comment: @Meghan, this `$20!="4T"` is controversial with initial condition *20 equals 5T, 6T, and 7T.*, how do you feel?